# Prevent removing trailing zeros on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Can anyone suggest a Google Sheets formula to stop removing trailing zeros? (but allow truncating to 6 digits after decimal? 00.000000

In D12 it shows: -98.508720
In G12, I need it to show: (1mi:29.519846:-98.508720)

GOOGLE DOC: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k4Xydv-VGmvIrwuidsmtXwUkGkSfJh0grmn4Pvh2qWQ/edit?usp=sharing

EXPLAINER VIDEO: https://www.loom.com/share/81e77eecdff04dda802b19cf566ac1f9

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the tags **before** posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].